# Cannot solve Ubongo Extreme B-38 purple puzzle

Tags: geometry, board-games

Today, I was playing **Ubongo Extreme** and I could NOT solve the following puzzle:
B-38, purple colour.

Let me know if you can solve it!

[image: Picture of the unsolvable game]

Comment: I'm stuck too - I'm not sure its possible (though I assume it is)...

Comment: I believe the pieces are reversible. [BGG has an English translation of the rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/28416/ubongo-extrem), which contains "The players now try to arrange their tiles on the card so as to match and cover the shape. The tiles can be placed with either of their sides face-up."

Answer (score 4):

Given that the pieces are reversible (see [comment from Jefromi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58261/cannot-solve-ubongo-extreme-b-38-purple-puzzle#comment178975_58261)):

> You just have to flip piece 3 over, then arrange them like so: [image]

Comment: Found that one too, but I assume they're not.

Comment: @RnRoger: Based on point 2 of the "Strategy"  section [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/296660/ubongo-extreme-better-original-pretty-much-every-w), I think they are. But admittedly I've never played this.

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure it sn't possible without flipping them -in which case it isn't that hard. I tried with powerpoint [ART](http://prntscr.com/hq7oan) but can't get it to fit without flipping.

Comment: I've played the game, and IIRC flipping the pieces is specifically allowed.